# Reading console input in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I am trying to a simple C# program that takes input and passes it as output. For instance, the output should be:

```
What is your name?
{user input}
Your name is {user input}
```

The program is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This is enclosed in a class called 'MainClass'

Its output is:

```
What is your name?
Your name is:
```

Why is this not working and how can I make it work?

P.S. I am using MonoDevelop and I added Console.ReadKey(); after the last WriteLine. No change.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Answer (score 45):

You are trying to type in the Application Output window in MonoDevelop and it is read-only.

You can configure MonoDevelop to automatically run the program at the command prompt by right clicking on the "options" menu item of your project and checking `Run on external console` under the `Run > General` tree.

[alt text http://psf.biz/public/monodevelop_run_on_external_console.jpg](http://psf.biz/public/monodevelop_run_on_external_console.jpg)

I guess the guy that gave me the -1 was blinded by that huge "Works on My Machine" emblem, nevertheless this *is* the correct and only answer.

Comment: I agree. When the question was posted, and my original answer was given, it said nothing about MonoDevelop

Comment: this does not work for a single file only non-project program.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Works on my machine]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi))</sub>

Is your problem that the program quits immediately after reading the console input? If so, then add a `Console.ReadKey();` after the last `WriteLine` so the program will wait for a keypress. Otherwise, I don't know what the problem is; I copy+pasted the code and it worked.