# Running program in external console in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652936/reading-console-input-in-monodevelop/740738#740738) that was given two years ago, but all I'm seeing now in the Options window is [image: this]

Where would the "Run on external console" option be located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window you posted is the MonoDevelop preferences window.

What you need to do is right-click your project in the Solution Explorer (I believe that's what it's called), and select `Options`.

There, you'll see `Run`, with `General` underneath. On that page is the `Run on external console` option.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MonoDevelop `7.1 build 1291` on `Linux` and I noticed that there are changes in menus. So if you want to disable `Run on External console`, first you need to open project options. right-click your `project` and click `options`. then you need to click `Run` -> `Configurations` -> `Default`. `Run on External console` option is in that page.