# Debugging c# in Xamarin or Visual Studio (preview) for mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I teach a c# programming class for a college. Currently, I have a VM running Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro.

When the students send me the zip file of their project I usually open the solution file in the VM, take a look at their code, and start without debugging.

Currently, when doing so in Xamarin or the new Visual Studio preview it just runs the entire program without letting me give any input. Such as if they have a Console.ReadLine() it will not stop for me to enter a value.

Is there something I am doing incorrect or what's going on?

Also, these are for console apps - I haven't tried GUI apps yet - but if I run the same program with Visual Studio 2015 for Windows it stops to allow input. Just wanting to take away as many steps as possible to grade these quicker.

Comment: _"By default, "C# -> Mac -> Xamarin.Mac" projects don't use an interactive console. Try creating a new solution, and pick "C# -> Console Project" in the New Solution window."_ - from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5438/can-put-nothing-on-input - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652936/reading-console-input-in-monodevelop